# jquery datatable Complex headers duplicate problem

Tags: jquery, datatable, duplicates

I am working with jquery datatable.

Here is my javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.withdraws').dataTable({
"sPaginationType": "bs_normal",
"aoColumns": [
  { "sTitle": "Transaction ID" },
  { "sTitle": "Receiver" },
  { "sTitle": "Receiver Phone" },
  { "sTitle": "Amount" },
  { "sTitle": "Service Fee" },
  { "sTitle": "Reference Text", "sClass": "center" },
  { "sTitle": "Date", "sClass": "center" }
    ]
}); 
$('.withdraws').each(function(){
var datatable = $(this);
var search_input = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] input');
search_input.attr('placeholder', 'Search');
search_input.addClass('form-control input-sm');
var length_sel = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_length] select');
length_sel.addClass('form-control input-sm');
        datatable.bind('page', function(e){
            window.console && console.log('pagination event:', e)
        });
   });
});
```

[image]

But i am facing duplicate header problem to work with jquery datatable.
Can you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: do you have more than one element with this class `withdraws`?

Comment: No, there is just one class name of withdraws witch used in that particular table.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, when binding and unbinding partial view contains script file. Remove the class contains datatable before creating the datatable in document.ready() function. I hope the below piece of would help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.withdraws').dataTable().destroy();  //Remove the datatable if exists and create it

$('.withdraws').dataTable({
 "sPaginationType": "bs_normal",
 "aoColumns": [
  { "sTitle": "Transaction ID" },
  { "sTitle": "Receiver" },
  { "sTitle": "Receiver Phone" },
  { "sTitle": "Amount" },
  { "sTitle": "Service Fee" },
  { "sTitle": "Reference Text", "sClass": "center" },
  { "sTitle": "Date", "sClass": "center" }
   ]
}); 
$('.withdraws').each(function(){
var datatable = $(this);
var search_input = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] input');
search_input.attr('placeholder', 'Search');
search_input.addClass('form-control input-sm');
var length_sel = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_length] select');
length_sel.addClass('form-control input-sm');
    datatable.bind('page', function(e){
        window.console && console.log('pagination event:', e)
    });
  });
});
```